# Smoothing Kinect Facetracking data

Tags: algorithm, kinect, tracking

I am trying to control a robot turret using Kinect Facetracking. When user moves his head, the turret moves in that same direction. I'm able to get the yaw, pitch and roll of the user's head and I control the turret using this data. My current attempts work, but do not move the turret fluidly. The movement is sporadic and choppy at times. What I want is smooth movements and a nice fluid motion.

So the main problem I have is that since the data is being received realtime, I cannot reliably predict what the user is going to do next. I need there to be as little lag as possible between the receiving the data and the commands.

Another problem is that the data coming from the Kinect is not perfect and sometimes fluctuates a bit. It's good data, but if I don't do something to it, then there will be choppiness.

How can I smooth out the data coming from the Kinect so that it is as fluid as possible?

I have some ideas, but I'd rather not influence you and cause you to think like me

Comment: Look into Kalman filtering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

Comment: I've heard of these before. Where can I see an implementation of this? Also, this program is already resource intensive and I don't know if it will be able to run fast enough for this.

Comment: Are you already setting `TransformSmoothParameters` (part of the Kinect SDK) in your code?

Comment: That helped a lot. I still need it smoother, but this is very good. What else do you recommend?

Comment: I am also interested in this and have tried double exponential smoothing and third order exponential smoothing. They sort of work, but introduce oscillation after every motion.

Comment: What is it that "helped a lot"? The Kalman filtering, or TransformSmoothParameters?

Comment: Initially it was the transformsmoothparameters. Then I stumbled upon the filter I listed below.

Answer (score 1):

The TransformSmoothParameters joint filtering helped some. But the most remarkable change happened when I stumbled upon this: http://www.dyadica.co.uk/journal/very-simple-kalman-in-c/
So basically just pass your data through update and it starts to filter it. Very impressed. Very simple. Works extraordinarily well. I think this is more of a moving average rather than Kalman filter, but it is exactly what I needed. Hope this helps those who are trying to do something similar.

```
        private double Q = 0.000001;
        private double R = 0.0001;
        private double P = 1, X = 0, K;

        private void measurementUpdate()
        {
            K = (P + Q) / (P + Q + R);
            P = R * (P + Q) / (R + P + Q);
        }

         public double update(double measurement)
        {
            measurementUpdate();
            double result = X + (measurement - X) * K;
            X = result;
           // Debug.WriteLine("Measurement " + result + " y: " + y);
            return result;
        }
```